# Oracle sql group function issues

Tags: sql, oracle

[image: ER DIagram]

3. Find Melbourne VIP level 4 customers’ first name, last name who have hired the vehicle model as “Ranger ” at least 2 times in database. You write three different queries: one is using operator EXISTS and the other one is using operator IN.  The third query with the main filter criteria in FROM clause of the main query or filter criteria in the sub-query.  Find one with the better performance.

I Have tried this query;

```
SELECT c_fname, c_fname FROM rental WHERE 
    EXISTS(SELECT c_id FROM customer WHERE c_city = 'Melbourne' AND customer.vip_level = '4')
    AND EXISTS (SELECT vehicle_reg FROM vehicle WHERE v_model = 'Ranger') 
    HAVING COUNT(c_id)>=2 GROUP BY c_lname, c_fname;
```

I am getting error: SQL Error: ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here
00934. 00000 -  "group function is not allowed here"

can anyone help me with this question. really struggled to get this done?

Answer (score -1):

You are selecting from the wrong subject table as `Rental` does not have `c_fname` or `c_lname` columns.

You want to "Find Melbourne VIP level 4 customers’ first name, last name" which would be in the `customer` table:

```sql
SELECT c_fname,
       c_lname
FROM   customer
WHERE  c_city    = 'Melbourne'
AND    vip_level = 4;
```

Then you want to add an additional filter "who have hired the vehicle model as “Ranger ” at least 2 times in database". That requires you to use `EXISTS` (for the answer for the first query) and you need to correlate between the outer-query and the sub-query; once you have done that then you do not need a `GROUP BY` clause and you are aggregating over the entire result set of the sub-query and can just use a `HAVING` clause.

```sql
SELECT c_fname,
       c_lname
FROM   customer c
WHERE  c_city    = 'Melbourne'
AND    vip_level = 4
AND    EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   rental r
                INNER JOIN vehicle v
                ON (r.vehicle_reg = v.vehicle_reg)
         WHERE  c.c_id = r.c_id
         AND    v.v_model = 'Ranger'
         HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
       );
```

Then you need to write the same query using `IN` instead of `EXISTS` and the same query a third time using `JOIN` conditions instead of `IN` or `EXISTS` and, finally, you need to compare the performance of all three queries.

Comment: i konw that, but he asked for a probllem that i mentioned and solved, and he has to provide three select make a bencmark test an select the best , so your solution is not what the user asked for

Comment: @nbk This appears to be a homework question and there is value in getting the OP to do their own homework so that they get the value from the activity.  Having helped them correct their attempt at the solution for the first part, in the final sentence I explain what else they need to do and leave it up to them to solve the rest of the question so they can get the benefit (as it is their homework and not someone elses).